# unable to generate custom image using initials android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i am trying to create an image view where if there is an image already in local storage then display that otherwise create a default image based on first letter of email.
here is the code->

```
val drawerEmailIdValue = "boy@gmail.com"
        val photoText = drawerEmailIdValue.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()

        val drawerPhoto = nav_view.getHeaderView(0).findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.drawerProfileImage)

        val f = File("/data/data/com.example.demoapp11/app_imageDirectory", "profileImage.jpg")

        if(f.exists()){
            val b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(FileInputStream(f))
            drawerPhoto.setImageBitmap(b)
        }else{
            val b = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            val c = Canvas(b)
            c.drawText(photoText, x.toFloat(), y.toFloat(), Paint())
            drawerPhoto.setImageBitmap(b)
        }
```

but i dont see any image when i open drawer menu. can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didnt do this approach. use this link and use this dependency instead.it pretty much does the work `https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable`

use this for gradle ->`implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'`

and finally this->

```
TextDrawable drawable2 = TextDrawable.builder()
                .buildRound(photoText, Color.RED);

drawerPhoto.setImageDrawable(drawable2);
```